# FlatButton's onPressed prints null for a variable whose value was set from TextField's onChange function

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When value changes in the `TextField`, I try to capture the change, print it and then assign it to the `newTaskTitle` variable. I can capture and print the change to console only from the `TextField`'s `onChange` function. But when I assign the value to `newTaskTitle`, it seems to work fine until I try to print it's value to console from the `FlatButton`'s `onPress` function which results to null. It appears as if the value was never assigned from the `TextField`'s `onChange` function at the first place.

The problem only goes away if `newTaskTitle` variable is moved up above the class definition.

What is the reason for this?

The code is shown below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String newTaskTitle;

    return Material(
      child: Container(
        color: Color(0xff757575),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Add Task',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (newText) {
                  newTaskTitle = newText;
                  // prints the equal value

                  print(newText);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Add',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                onPressed: () {
                  print(newTaskTitle);
                  // Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // prints null

                  print(newTaskTitle);
                  // Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot see the issue, but you can try bringing ````String newTaskTitle;```` outside build function, if your Scaffold rebuilds "to avoid bottom padding", then your widget is rebuilt when keyboard is closed, so the string is reassigned too.

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: There's something else going on, you probably need to show more code. I just tried yours in a brand new project and didn't see any issue.

Comment: I actually have this same problem, I edited the question (which is awaiting peer review) and provided more context which I happen to have because I was following the same flutter course at appbrewery.co (by Angela Yu).
But if you've found a solution you could share.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should try moving the `String newTaskTitle;` from the build function and then make it a static property. So it becomes `static String newTaskTitle;`

Comment: Thank you, Alfred, I was struggling and just moved the static variable out of the build function and it works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I just changed AddTaskScreen class to a statefull widget and moved the newTaskTitle variable outside the build method instead of declaring it inside the build method and it worked.
Hope It helps somebody.

Answer (score -1):

I would suspect that this line `newTaskTitle = newText;` does not rebuild your page. Try to make it as a page's state by bringing it outside the build function.

```
String newTaskTitle;

@override
void build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
```

Try wrapping it inside `setState()`.

```
setState(() => newTaskTitle = newText);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because the component is not re-built, so the printed value will always be the initial one (ie null) and not the one you update with the TextField.

You can re-built your Build method only in Statefull component. You can make one of the or changing the entire structure, or using the [StatefullBuilder()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html)

First you have to change the position of your variable:

```
String newTaskTitle;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 ...
}
```

Second, you have to use setstate() and, in this case, you have two options:

First Option:

```
    TextField(
      onChanged: (newText) => setState(() => newTaskTitle = newText),    
    ),
```

Second Option:

```
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {});
        print(newTaskTitle)
      }
    )
```